# Java DOM parser returns null document

Tags: java, dom, null, document, domparser

I have an HTML template which I want to read in:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>TEST</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 id="hey">Hello, World!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

I want find the tag with the id `hey` and then paste in new stuff (e.g. new tags). For this purpose I use the DOM parser. But my code returns me `null`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\template.html");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println(doc.getElementById("hey")); // returns null

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to parse a piece of XML with the Java XML API, that is very compliant with the XML specification and doesn't help the casual developer.

In XML an attribute named `id` is not automatically of `ID` type, and thus the XML implementation doesn't  get it with `.getElementById()`. Either you use another library (Jsoup for example), or instruct the parser to treat `id` as an ID (via the DTD) or you use custom code.

Comment: Ok, I understand! Thx, I will try this solution (edit: I mean Jsoup) now and tell if it worked.

Comment: Just for fun, here you a [working gist](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/f37be9078a73e7e90383)

Comment: Thanks a lot (for the answer and the gist). It worked! And even if I would have a working solution using DOM with your gist, I will go the Jsoup way since this is more the way I am "thinking" because I worked a lot in the JQuery/CSS/JavaScript domain and it is soo intuitive! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I modified your example to using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\template.html");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF8");          
            Element elementById = doc.getElementById("hey");
            System.out.println("hey ="+doc.getElementById("hey").ownText());
            System.out.println("hey ="+doc.getElementById("hey"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, works, too. I like this library since I can use everything like in JavaScript. It makes everything more comfortable than in DOM/SAX!